# Advice on SQL structure and maybe JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I made a similar thread about a month back but i quickly realized I didn't ask the right questions. So I'm gonna try this again.

I have a database with two tables, one user-table and one fish-table.

In my user-table I have `user_id, username, email` etc etc.(`user_ID PK`).

In my fish-table I have `fish_id, weight, length` etc etc. (`fish_ID PK`).

When a user is logged in he is able to register a fish. This is where my problem occurs.
**I need to know which user has registered what fish.**

```
"$query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `fish` (`fish`, `weight`, `length`, `lure`, `comment`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");"
```

That is how my query now looks like. I assume I have to make a user_id column in my fish-table but I have no idea how to register the user_id who uploaded the fish.

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a user_id column to your fish table like you said. When a user registers a fish, you'd have to insert his user_id at the same time. I suppose you use sessions to keep the users logged in, so you should have a session variable containing the user id.

Comment: What the.. of course! Thanks. How could I not even think of that? thx m8

Answer (score 0):

You should create another transaction table, which will keep track of registration of fish by users.

```
User_fishes(id, user_id, fish_id, registration_date,..)
```

In this table you can keep track of which user has registered what fish.